# some images not showing in Magento ver. 2.1.0

Tags: media-images

```
Magento 2.1.0
Porto theme
```

I have installed Magento 2.1.0 and the Porto theme. I have made no additional changes whatsoever except I tried to clear Cache and re-index (which I guess can't be done through the Admin panel no more?)

Now what happens is - some images are completely missing such as on the Payment page - it's missing the "Acceptance Mark" (that's the alternate text for the image anyways) for PayPal Express Checkout. I'm also missing the logo in the top left hand corner of the Admin page (which I changed and then it was showing fine) and the Magento Admin Panel logo on the login into the Admin panel page. [image]

Any ideas what I did to cause this and how to fix it and make sure these images do not go away in the future?

I will include 3 screen-shots of what I'm talking about...

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should run `php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` this command. and then give full permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can run below command from magento root folder.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This will download the content perfectly in respective folders.

set permission if needed after running above command.

Thanks

Comment: Would this mess up the graphics/design I got going from the Porto theme? The images were there before but later disappeared... What are the correct permissions? Thank you for helping! ;-)

Comment: `chmod -R 777 pub` and `chmod -R 777 var`.. it wont mess up anything. It will just regenerate content inside pub folder

Comment: Thank you. Last question - can I chmod the pub and var directories to 777 via FTP? I know how to do that...

Comment: Right click on the folder like var or pub and enter 777 in Numeric Value.. and check "Recuse into sub directories" to TRUE.

Comment: does it works ?